# Web app to find a celebrity face match for a given portrait

Tags: webapp-rec, images

Is there a web app that can find a celebrity face match for an uploaded portrait?

Comment: Google Image Search?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Pictriev](http://www.pictriev.com/facedb/fs2.php) is exactly for this purpose. You give it a picture and it will find other pictures of the same person.

I've tried a few examples using pictures from the internet with varying degrees of success - it seems to give better results if the person is "more famous" (ie. there are more images of them on the internet).

Answer (score 0):

You could try [tineye.com](http://tineye.com), which will show you other sites that have similar images hosted on them. Then you could go to one of these sites and it might have a caption which says who the person is.

Comment: Got distracted by one of the kids :(